# SVG Rect Height to Match fo:block height

Tags: svg, xsl-fo, apache-fop

This is a shot in the dark, but is there a way to set the svg rect height based on the `fo:block` height?

I've got a design where the client assumes the static graphic can scale in a `fo:table-row` where text is wrapping. The static graphic has a very particular shape.

I'm trying to find a solution to scale the graphic height based on it's parent.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is the image on the block (i.e. it is in one table-cell in a block) or on the whole table-row? Also, explain the scaling desired in both directions (you state height scaling to fit, what happens with the width?). it the graphic non-uniformly scaled or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to place a scaled background image behind a block in the table-cell (question was unclear) ... you can do so using RenderX XEP with their extensions for background-images.

See http://www.renderx.com/reference.html#Background_Image

Sample:

```
  <fo:table>
        <fo:table-column column-width="1in"/>
        <fo:table-column column-width="1in"/>
        <fo:table-column column-width="1in"/>
        <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row >
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block background-repeat="no-repeat" background-position="center center" background-image="circles1.svg" rx:background-content-height="scale-to-fit" rx:background-content-width="scale-to-fit" rx:background-scaling="non-uniform">This is some flowing stuff. This is some flowing stuff. This is some flowing stuff. This is some flowing stuff. </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block background-repeat="no-repeat" background-position="center center" background-image="circles1.svg" rx:background-content-height="scale-to-fit" rx:background-content-width="scale-to-fit" rx:background-scaling="non-uniform">This is some flowing stuff. </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block background-repeat="no-repeat" background-position="center center" background-image="circles1.svg" rx:background-content-height="scale-to-fit" rx:background-content-width="scale-to-fit" rx:background-scaling="non-uniform"> This is some flowing stuff. This is some flowing stuff. This is some flowing stuff. This is some flowing stuff. This is some flowing stuff. This is some flowing stuff. This is some flowing stuff. This is some flowing stuff. </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
```

Result:

[image]